# Run methods even when the application has been closed

Tags: flutter, background, foreground-service

I have a method that works like a timer. When a certain time is reached, the app is capable of sending a push notification to the user. The problem with this is that I have only gotten this method to work when the app is running in the background or when the user is running the app.

My question is if there is any way to keep this method running even when the user has completely close the application, regardless of whether it is on Android or iOS.

Answer (score 0):

if your needs to work in background then use Flutter Background Service and Put that function onStart method,
**it will works while your app in Background Mode and it's not running,**

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service

```
flutter_background_service: ^2.4.6
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I tried before that package, and it doesn't solve my needs because even if it works in background mode, doesn't work in foreground (when the app is closed)